# Django Not Recognizing Multiple Databases

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use multiple databases with my Django project but it is only recognizing the default one. In my settings.py file I have the following set:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "primary",
        "USER": "admin",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "",
        "PORT": "",
},
    "deals": {
        "ENGINE": 'django_mongodb_engine',
        "NAME": "database",
        "HOST": "HOSTNAME",
        "PORT": "27017",
        "USER": "",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS": False,
    },
}
```

But when I try to run

```
python manage.py syncdb --database=deals
```

or

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=deals
```

I am getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection deals doesn't exist
```

When I try to debug in /lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py I am seeing that only the default database is being recognized. I get the same error when I try to create a second local database.

**EDIT**
I've updated my settings.py file according to the comments but still have the same issue.

Comment: The documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#engine says you should use fully qualified path. The one for `deals` is not fully qualified. The one for `default` is incomplete.

Comment: I've made some changes according to the comment but still have the same issue. I fixed the default database, but can't seem to find the fully qualified path for mongodb, as the MongoDB documentation at (https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html) says to use django_mongodb_engine

Comment: Do you have several settings files where DATABASE is set?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the indentation? I checked it with my code, it looks ok. Or it does not support multiple Databases with MongoDB.

Comment: Indentation doesn't matter in a dict body. Moreover Python would throw IndentationError if that was the case.